# HaXml: Trouble reading in the data from the XML file

Tags: xml, parsing, haskell

I'm struggling to understand how to use HaXml to parse the following XML file (as an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <author>Mark</author>
  <year>2012</year>
</root>
```

Specifically, how do I:

- Identify that the XML document is *well-formed* (I assume that I use the function xmlParse, which should hopefully do this for me)
- Identify that the XML document is *valid*
- Find the  tag and read the *string* "Mark" into a value of type String
- Find the  tag and read the *number* 2012 into a value of type Int

The (rather sparse) HaXml documentation doesn't seem very helpful and any blog/Stackoverflow entries are sketchy on this at best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I solved my own question.

Basically `xmlParse` checks that the document is well-formed and a Unix command-line tool `Validate` checks that an `.xml` file conforms to an associated `.dtd` file.

To find a specific tag drill-down into the document using the `/>` operator.

So use something like `tag <tagname1> /> tag <tagname2> /> txt $ getContents xmlContents`

Here `xmlContents` is the result of `xmlParse` and `getContents` is defined as

`getContents (Document _ _ e _) = CElem e noPos`